# Send log to Rsyslog server with go

Tags: linux, go

I write a code to send log to rsyslog server on ubuntu, the code has below content. In the file ryslogd.conf I have configured local7.* /var/log/test.log.*But when running, the log is not written to the test.log
*

```
package main
import (
        "errors"
        "fmt"
        "log/syslog"
        "os"
        "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
        programName := filepath.Base(os.Args[0])
        fmt.Println(programName)
        syslog_pointer, err := syslog.Dial("udp", "localhost:514", syslog.LOG_WARNING|syslog.LOG_LOCAL7, "test")
        if err != nil {
                err_exception := errors.New("Can't connect to syslog server localhost:514")
                fmt.Println(err_exception)
                os.Exit(1)
        } else {
                syslog_pointer.Emerg("This is log test")
        }
}
```

I want the log line: this is test log to be written to the file /var/log/test.log

Answer (score 0):

Local logging is typically via a Unix socket. UDP logging typically needs to be explicitly enabled for the Syslog server.

Creating the `syslog.Writer` via `syslog.New` will attempt to connect via common Unix sockets first, then attempt UDP via localhost:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "log/syslog"
)

func main() {
    s, err := syslog.New(syslog.LOG_WARNING|syslog.LOG_LOCAL7, "test")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    s.Emerg("log test")
}
```